# Liquibase: Хранение данных в колонке sql скриптом

Tags: sql, json, liquibase

Есть колонка `user` и в этой колонке надо сохранять JSON объект с полями name,country,generate.

Если generate = false

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А какая проблема возникает? Для добавления строки - insert. Обновление - update. Конечно, стоит спросить ещё, зачем хранить информацию в json, когда можно создать несколько столбцов (в вашем случае, 3 столбца "name", "country", "generane")